# Problems with syntax in PHP

Tags: php, object, syntax, properties

I have an object and can access one of its properties by

```
$book = new Book(); print $book->price;
```

I can also call

```
 $prop = "price"; print $book->$prop.
```

But I cannot figure out how to call in a mixed way, it gives error:

```
$book->id_$prod
```

as a shortened of $book->id_products, being $prod = "products".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$book = new Book(); 
$id_prod = "id_$prod";
print $book->$id_prod;
```

Comment: Is this the only way? No possibility of using {} or something? It reminds me of dereferencing of objects, like $object->method()[0] which was incorrect until PHP 5.4 I think, you should make $tmp =$object->method(), and later access $tmp[0].

Comment: yes, you could also do print $book->{"id_$prod"};

Answer (score 1):

Mix the 2 first options.

```
$prop = 'id_'.$prod;
$book->$prop;
```

Comment: That is trivial. I meant a direct way with some trick. For example {"id_" . $prod} or something.

Comment: It seems it works: $book->{"id_" . $prod}